# awk change once per file

Tags: awk, gawk

```
awk -i inplace '
  BEGIN {FS=" "}
  BEGINFILE {changed=0} 
  { print;if ($1 == "namespace" && !changed) {print "foo";changed=1} }
' *
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? Some built-in construct I missed? I am running GNU Awk 4.1.0 (and I am superb glad for -i inplace).

Comment: You could surely write it to make it somewhat shorter, but I guess that the logic would be similar.

Comment: I am curious about the shorter version. I am always eager to learn :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -i inplace '$1=="namespace" && !seen[ARGIND]++ {$0=$0 ORS "foo"} 1' *
```

`FS=" "` is the default, no need to specify it explicitly.

Comment: That's very tricky. ARGIND is the index in ARGV of the file name so it changes per file and I presume an uninitialized variable is empty, negated it  becomes true-ish, incremented and negated will be false-ish so it fires once per file indeed.

Comment: It's not tricky, just idiomatic. Using an array named `seen[]` that way is an extremely common awk idiom for only operating on the first occurrence of anything. Yes, ARGIND is the gawk-only index in the ARGV array of the file currently being processed. You could use FILENAME instead but there's different semantics if the same file appears multiple times on the arg list. `seen[x]++` is false the first time it's evaluated since `seen[x]` starts as `zero-or-null` then is post incremented so every subsequent time `seen[x]++` is true. `!seen[x]++` is the opposite - true first time then false after.

Answer (score 1):

You could say:

```
... -F' ' '$1 == "namespace" && !a {$0=$0 RS "foo";a=1}1' file
```

or even:

```
... -F' ' '$1 == "namespace" && !_ {$0=$0 RS "foo";_=1}1' file
```

As mentioned in the comment above, this is pretty similar to what you've written except that it uses the `RS` variable to insert the text.

---

In order to do this for multiple files, you'd need to reset the variable:

```
... -F' ' 'BEGINFILE {a=0} $1 == "namespace" && !a {$0=$0 RS "foo";a=1}1' *
```

or

```
... -F' ' 'FNR==1 {a=0} $1 == "namespace" && !a {$0=$0 RS "foo";a=1}1' *
```

Comment: I see, you are using [Expression patterns](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Expression-Patterns) which are new to me. But what's the 1 at the end?

Comment: OMG the 1 is an expression and the pattern can be empty? So that's basically a shorthand for `{print}`. Super tricky.

Comment: @chx Right `1` is a shorthand for `print`.  You might also see some use `42` instead!

Comment: Hrm this will execute once in total and not once per file.

Comment: @chx Right, in order to execute it for multiple files you'd need to reset the variable to 0 at the beginning.  See edit above.

Comment: Doesn't `{a=0}` need BEGINFILE (and if not, then why not?)

Comment: @chx `{a=0}` would actually need a [`BEGINFILE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE.html) pattern.

Comment: @chx Alternatively, you could use [`FNR`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Auto_002dset).  See edit above.