# awk difference between 1 and {print}?

Tags: awk

This comment on [awk change once per file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185553/awk-change-once-per-file#comment30094934_20185845) made me think `1` and `{print}` are equal in awk. But it is not.

```
awk '/^\S/ {core=0} /^_core/ {core=1} !core 1' views.view.who_s_online.yml|head
uuid: 50715f68-3b13-4a15-8455-853110fd1d8b
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - user
_core:
  default_config_hash: DWLCIpl8ku4NbiI9t3GgDeuW13KSOy2l1zho7ReP_Bg
id: who_s_online
label: 'Who''s online block'
```

Compare to (and this is what I wanted btw):

```
awk '/^\S/ {core=0} /^_core/ {core=1} !core {print}' views.view.who_s_online.yml|head
uuid: 50715f68-3b13-4a15-8455-853110fd1d8b
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - user
id: who_s_online
label: 'Who''s online block'
module: user
description: 'Shows the user names of the most recently active users, and the total number of active users.'
```

Comment: You seem to have a habit of accepting an answer very soon after asking your question. In the question you referenced you accepted the first answer you got within half an hour of asking it which is why you only got 1 answer, everyone else just skipped it and moved on to see if we could help anyone still looking for an answer (I've added an an answer now). I'm not saying the first answer you get won't be the best answer but MAYBE going forward you should hold off for a few hours or even a day before accepting an answer just to see what other suggestions you get. Couldn't hurt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure of an awk program is a series of conditions and actions:

```
condition { action }
```

The default value of `condition` is `1` (true), so actions without a condition always happen:

```
{ action } # is equivalent to
1 { action }
```

The default action is `print`, so quite often you will see a `1` in an awk script instead of `{ print }`.

However, in your script, your condition is `!core 1`. This will negate the value of `core`, coerce it to a string and concatenate with the string `"1"`. A non-empty string is always true, so every record will be printed.

If you want to only print records where `core` is false, then you can use `!core` as a condition by itself.

Answer (score 3):

#### Yes, they are the same.

These expressions are completely equivalent:

```
awk '1' file
awk '{print}' file
awk '42' file
awk '2342352' file
awk '{print $0}' file
```

Why? Because a True condition triggers awk's default action: to print the current record; that is, `{print $0}`.

#### Now, what is happening here?

You are using them in a different way. In one case, you are saying:

```
awk '{things...} !core 1' file
#                ^^^^^^^
```

In this case, `!core` is not doing anything. It reads as just `awk '{things...} 1' file`. Or better see [Tom Fenech's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39222417/1983854) on it.

You can test it by executing both `seq 10 | awk '/5/ {core++} 1'` and `seq 10 | awk '/5/ {core++} !core'`. Both return all the numbers from 1 to 10. Instead, you would like to use `seq 10 | awk '/5/ {core++} !core'` to print from 1 to 4.

<sub>Notice also the difference with:</sub>

```
awk '{things...} !core; 1' file
#                     ^
```

<sub>By having this semi colon, this will trigger the action in `!core` (that is, to print the current record -line- if core evaluates to False) and then `1` will make it print all the records, no matter any condition. So `seq 10 | awk '/5/ {core++} !core; 1'` will print from 1 to 10, printing 1 to 4 twice.</sub>

On the other case you say:

```
awk '{things...} !core {print}' file
#                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This reads as: *if core evaluates to False, then do `print`*.

#### What is the reason behind them being equivalent?

This is because `awk` works on the syntax `condition { action }`, which can have `{ action }` suppressed when it consists in the default action: `{print $0}`. This way, whenever you want an action to be always triggered, you can say either `{print $0}` or just use the `condition` part with a True condition, like `1`, `42`, a variable that you already set to a positive value, etc.

Then, this is also useful to make awk code more idiomatic: if you work with variables as a flag, you can say `var` and it will trigger the `print` whenever the flag is set to a True condition, likewise you do with `core` in your code. This way, these two awk expressions are equivalent:

```
awk '/5/ {core++} core'
awk '/5/ {core++} { if (core > 0) {print $0}}'
awk '{ if ($0~/5/) {core++}} { if (core > 0) {print $0}}'
```

See how using idiomatic code makes it look better? ;)

Check [GNU Awk User's Guide → 7.3 Actions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Action-Overview) for a more technical explanation (and probably better wording than mine!):

> An awk program or script consists of a series of rules and function
>   definitions interspersed. (Functions are described later. See
>   User-defined.) A rule contains a pattern and an action, either of
>   which (but not both) may be omitted. The purpose of the action is to
>   tell awk what to do once a match for the pattern is found. Thus, in
>   outline, an awk program generally looks like this:
>
> ```
> [pattern]  { action }
>  pattern  [{ action }]
> …
> function name(args) { … }
> …
> ```
>
> An action consists of one or more awk statements, enclosed in braces
>   (‘{…}’). Each statement specifies one thing to do. The statements are
>   separated by newlines or semicolons. The braces around an action must
>   be used even if the action contains only one statement, or if it
>   contains no statements at all. However, if you omit the action
>   entirely, omit the braces as well. An omitted action is equivalent to
>   ‘{ print $0 }’:
>
> ```
> /foo/  { }     match foo, do nothing — empty action
> /foo/          match foo, print the record — omitted action
> ```

Comment: As asked on Meta, here's why I accepted Tom Fenech's answer: 1) he starts with stating awk runs condition-action pairs, you start out presuming I know this (which I sorta do but apparently not enough) 2) it makes clear that what I wrote is a single condition 3) he makes a good suggestion on shortening my code. Your is better with the semicolon'd example. His is short and yet it explains my wrong presumptions and corrects them.

Comment: @chx good one! Very kind of you. I would've also accepted Tom Fenech's answer. Just for reference: [your meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333459/1983854). I always find it hard to know what to do in situations like this, when two answers come in the same moment and reply something similar: I don't want to overtake the other, so I kind of freeze mine and try not to repeat anything that is in the other one. Probably a combined answer would be the best thing for future readers.