# how awk print the regex it maps?

Tags: regex, linux, awk

Here is the file contents:

```
# cat text 
16:10:29 DEBUG MY_Output:90 1 5de0d275c2f55: send response
```

As I do regex map with `awk`:

```
# cat text | awk '{if($0~/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.*/) print $0}'
(print nothing)

# cat text | awk '/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.*/ {print $0}'
(print nothing)

# cat text | awk '/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.*/1'
16:10:29 DEBUG MY_Output:90 1 5de0d275c2f55: send response
```

**My Question is:**
why `{if($0~/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.*/) print $0}` , `/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.*/ {print $0}` print nothing, but `/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.*/1` print the result.

As I expected, the three expressions play the same meaning, as  [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39222230/awk-difference-between-1-and-print) describes, `1`,  `{print}`, `{print $0}` do the same thing in action.

Also the another experiment likely to check:

```
# awk '{if(/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/) print $0}' <<< "16:10:29" 
(print nothing)

# awk '/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/{print $0}' <<< "16:10:29"
(print nothing)

# awk '/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/1' <<< "16:10:29"
16:10:29
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: The first two commands work fine here, they print the line. Third one will always print input lines since it evaluates to either `"01"` or `"11"`; compare to `echo foo | awk '/b/1'`

Comment: What is the version of your `awk`?

Comment: ```GNU Awk 3.1.7```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After knowing OP's `awk` version(in comments section) looks like it it OLD one so `[0-9]{2}` is NOT supported in it(I believe so), so can you try following command once.

```
awk '/[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/' Input_file
```

This should work with your provided `awk` version.

---

---

Also with old version of `awk` you could use `--re-interval` to get it worked, I don't have that version with me so couldn't test it.

```
awk --re-interval '/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/'  Input_file
```

In older versions of `awk` to invoke EREs we need to include `--re-interval` with `awk` codes, hence it is NOT working with normal `awk` code.

***NOTE:*** In new versions of `gawk`s `--re-interval` is depreciated since OP has old version of `awk` so have mentioned it in solution. Adding cross site reference link https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354553/awk-repetition-n-is-not-working as per OP's comments too here.

Comment: It works for both commands like ```awk '/[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9].*/' text``` and ```awk '/[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9].*/' <<< "16:45:01"```.    It seems ```[0-9]{2}``` does not work in ```GNU Awk 3.1.7``` but ```[0-9][0-9]```?

Comment: @heming621, I used to have this OLD version so I know this glitch :) Now comes part why `[0-9]{2}` is NOT working, IMHO that comes in category of ERE(extended regular expressions) which was supported in OLD `awk` once you involve `--re-interval` in your `awk` code, please check my 2nd code on same. In new versions of `awk|gawk` `--re-interval` is strongly depreciated and we need NOT to use it too, please check that option once and you will get more clarity on my statements, cheers.

Comment: @ RavinderSingh And I found this explanation [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354553/awk-repetition-n-is-not-working), maybe this is the reason why {N} does no work in Awk 3.X. Thanks again.

Comment: Why ```awk '/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/1'``` works? The ```{2}``` also be applied in ```awk```.

Comment: @heming621, It works how oguz ismail explained in comments, `awk` works on method of condition and then action, so by mentioning `1` you are maing condition part true and not mentioning any action so default print of the current line will happen.

Comment: As I understand from your explanation, the ```'/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/1'``` entirety is applied as _condition_ part  in awk, which makes _action_ part print default. Why ```1``` can not just be as the replacement of  ```{print $0}``` in expression ```'/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/1'```, which translate as  ```'/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/{print $0}'```?

Comment: @heming621, So `/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/` is a condition itself, so when we put `/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/{print}` which is EQUAL to `/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/` since as I mentioned before too,if NO action is mentioned then default action print of line will happen. Now coming on `/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/1` doesn't mean that 1st is condition and `1` is an action, it means there are 2 conditions since 1st is never passing so 1 is printing it, when both will pass then it should print the line twice. You could give it a try by doing `/[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9].*/1` once.

Comment: I try ```awk '/[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9].*/1' <<< "19:19:07"```, it print line once. And ```awk '/[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9].*/{print}1' <<< "19:19:07"``` print the line twice.

Comment: @heming621, yeah the 2nd one make sense since print and 1 are doing something. For first one need to check it once. Thank you for checking it.